# Magento duplicated shipping rates on multishipping checkout

Tags: php, magento

I have a strange issue on multishipping checkout where rates are duplicated from the address above it. Anyone know what causes this? I can't find any information about it.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Check the Webshopapps Handlingproduct (or other extensions overriding shipping model) config.xml file: model is declared incorrectly.

Just delete

```
<shipping><rewrite>...</rewrite></shipping>
```

Should help.